# Como aplicarle una funcion a un array

Tags: php, array, wordpress, funciones

Necesito aplicarle una función a una variable que devuelve este array:

```
"content_block_images": [
      {
        "image": 10741
      },
      {
        "image": 10742
      }
    ]
```

Pero esta función solo acepta que se le ingrese la id simplemente que serian estas 10741. Como la función lo acepta seria así función (10741), alguna solución? PD: Necesito los datos asi como estan en json porque esto lo tengo que devolver en una API lo unico que quiero hacer es que en lugar de la id se muestre la url de la imagen para lo cual hay que usar esta funcion wp_get_attachment_url().

Y lo que estoy tratando de convertir a url es un array multidimensional

Answer (score 2):

No se mucho de PHP, pero lo que deberías hacer (en cualquier lenguaje de programación) es:

1. convertir el JSON a un array
2. iterar sobre el array
3. aplicar la función a cada uno de los elementos.

Supongo que en PHP quedará algo así:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
$array = $data->content_block_images;
foreach ($array as $clave => $valor) {
    funcion($valor);
}
```

Comment: En si esto no quiero convertirlo porque lo que estoy haciendo es devolverlo en una API, lo que yo necesito es aplicar una funcion para que en lugar de devolver las ID devuelva las url esa funcion es una funcion de wordpress que convierte la id a la url wp_get_attachment_url()

Comment: Si no quieres modificar un `string` entonces puedes trabajar con expresiones regulares para extraer los valores que quieres, mandarlos a la función que necesitas y luego reemplazar esos valores (en el mismo string). Es decir, es tan descabellado y sin sentido como suena. Toma el consejo de @marcos-crispino, luego vuelves a armar tu objeto con `json_encode`